# How to merge the two cells(columns) of cross-tab in BIRT eclipse design?

Tags: eclipse, birt

I'm using birt report designer for create a report: In my report i have a crossTab to show the static data. It should look like the attached image.
[image]

**What I managed to design is :**
[image]

So How to merge these cells (columns) into one; like what's there in the first image. I mean I want 'StudentId', 'StudentName' and 'Level' under one column only i.e. **"Assessment Information"**

Answer (score 1):

This layout seems to be a standard table, not a crosstab. Crosstabs allow to compute measures across dimensions, such Excel pivot tables.

Have a look at [this standard table sample](http://www.visioneo.org/autocomplete), a few columns are merged under "Institution":

[image: Merged columns in birt table]

To achieve this result, we have to select the header row -> insert row -> above an then merge cells just as we would do it with Excel.

Comment: Dominique, unfortunately this is a cross-tab :(. NOt finding any solution to merge the cells in cross-tab.

Comment: ok. May be you should expand what the underlying datacube of the  crosstab looks like: for example it is not clear if studentID, studendName and level are 3 levels of a same group, or something else. It would probably help to get an overview of the crosstable design, showing both row groups, column groups and measures